# how to get all the indicesr when '"fo"','"ba"' appear together. in Python?

Tags: python, list, function, indices

For a list of lists `['"fo"', '"ba"', '1','2','ect.','"fo"', '"ba"','ect.','57','"trip"']` , what's the cleanest way to get all the indices for '"fo"' when '"fo"','"ba"' appear together in the list. in Python?

Similar to one edited for 1 item  answered Dec 30'14 at 21:03 and Edited Jul 28 at 21:30  by MrWonderful 
For a list `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` and an item in the list "bar", what's the cleanest way to get its index (1) in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for `'"fo"'` immediately followed by `'"ba"'`, something like

```
import itertools

l = ['"fo"', '"ba"', '1','2','ect.','"fo"', '"ba"','ect.','57','"trip"']
print([i for i, x in enumerate(zip(l, itertools.islice(l, 1, None))) if x == ('"fo"', '"ba"')])
```

Comment: ok- this looks perfect for what i think i want to do now.  it gave me a list of over 80 indices  which it what it should be.  i need to learn about finding itertools and random and other modules and how to use them. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
for one_list in list_of_lists:
    if ("fo" in one_list ) and ("ba" in one_list):
        return indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(one_list) if x == "fo"]
```

Comment: i'm new at all this.  this is what i have been trying.  i found something would give the indices for 1 list, and i got it to work.  now i want it to search for instances where 2 lists appear together.  this is what i am trying.

Comment: def indices(l, val):
    """Always returns a list containing the indices of val in the_list"""
    retval = []
    last = 0
    while val in l[last:]:
            i = l[last:].index(val)    #finds index last item in list
            if l[i+1] == date:
                print(l[last])
                print(l[last+1])
                retval.append(last + i)
                last += i + 1   
            elif l[i+1] != date:
               last += i 
    return retval

Comment: l = no_spaces
q = ('"EMD"')
date =('"20170820"')
print (indices(l,q))
print (indices(l,'"EMD"'))       i tried kogito's solution and kept getting   File "c:\code\testing.py", line 16
    return indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(one_list) if x == no_spaces[0]]
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax   thank you all   i want to try patrick's and windmill's posts also to see if i can work them into my program.

Comment: Please format your comments correctly so we can answer you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this! We iterate through the list once, checking if the index we are on and the next thing down match what you want. If it does, we add it to a list. We also check that we are not on the last index of the list to avoid indexOutOfBounds exceptions.

```
results = []
for i in range(0, len(lst)):
    if i < len(lst)-1 and lst[i] == '"fo"' and lst[i+1] == '"ba"':
        results.append(i)
return results
```

Note that this works for your example, which looks to be a single list rather than a list of lists. To apply to lists of lists, you could add an extra for loop iteration through each sublist.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with.  I adapted Patrick Haugh's answer.

```
import itertools         # C-D    create list of indices    
r_va=('"EMD"', '"20170820"')
L = ([i for i, x in enumerate(zip(l, itertools.islice(l, 1, None))) if \
x == (r_va)])
e =(len(l))
L.append(e)    # adds end length of no_spaces   L is list of indexes of l
```